I work with Spring Boot and REST template. I want to get the information of user connect
I work with Spring Boot and REST template.  I want to get the information of user connect but I get the information just if I connect with admin account and not the author account.  This is my code
public UserDto getInfo() throws APIErrorException {

        UserInfoResponse userInfoResponse = null;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("token", accessToken);
        map.add(CLIENT_ID, admin_Client);
        map.add(CLIENT_SECRET, secret_key);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        try {
            userInfoResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(userInfoUrl, request, UserInfoResponse.class).getBody();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new APIErrorException(ErrorCode.E444);
        }
        UserKeycloak userKeycloak = userMapperService.fromUserInfoResponse(userInfoResponse);
        return userMapperService.convertKeycloakToDto(userKeycloak);
    }


What is your issue here ?  Also what is UserInfoResponse ?

And which service are you trying to get info from ? Or is it a test ?

I suspect you're trying to get user info from Keycloak, correct? If so, this might be a permission issue in Keycloak itself and has nothing to do with Spring or RestTemplate. A normal user might just not be authorized to use this API.

userinfoResponse it the object containe the information return by keycloack

how can i modifiy the permetion in keycloack

@BDurand userinfoResponse it the object containe the information return by keycloack

Spring Security OAuth2 Client by default should be calling the userinfo endpoint using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService and will add the user attributes to a OAuth2UserAuthority.

As you're working with Keycloak, the access token is most probably a JWT, in which case you'd better decode it, rather than "introspecting" it on the userinfo endpoint (this would be faster and put less contention on your authorization server).
That said, userinfo endpoint expects the Bearer access token as Authorization header (and client ID and secret are most probably useless). Try:
public UserDto getInfo() throws APIErrorException {
    final var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
    HttpEntity<Void> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    try {
        final var userInfoResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(userInfoUrl, request, UserInfoResponse.class).getBody();
        final var userKeycloak = userMapperService.fromUserInfoResponse(userInfoResponse);
        return userMapperService.convertKeycloakToDto(userKeycloak);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new APIErrorException(ErrorCode.E444);
    }
}


@guost I am surprised this didn't help...
